# How to get Distinct elements from a List of List in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of list, where the child list is list of string. The result i am expecting is list of all distinct strings.
For eg:

```
var listoflist = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" },
                                          new List<string> { "A", "B", "D", "E" } };
```

For the above list i expecting the output as {"A","B","C","D","E"}

This is the solution that i found , but i dont feels its a efficient solution.Please provide your thougths on this.

```
var listoflist = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" },
                                          new List<string> { "A", "B", "D", "E" } };

List<string> distinctList = new List<string>();
listoflist.ForEach(list =>
{
    distinctList.AddRange(list);
});

distinctList = distinctList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) to flatten the lists:

```
var list = listoflist.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
```

If you want to materialize the query and get a `List<string>`, add `ToList()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here,

```
[TestClass]
public class Class1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void test()
    {
        var listoflist = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"},
            new List<string> {"A", "B", "D", "E"}
        };
        var result = listoflist.SelectMany(l=>l).Distinct().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var res = listoflist.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
```

`SelectMany` will flatten the list from which on which you can apply the Distinct method. It will return `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want `List<string>` as output then simply apply a `ToList` which will materialize the result:-

```
List<string> distinctList = listoflist.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listofList.SelectMany().Distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use,

`var distinctValues= listoflist[0].Concat(listoflist[1]).GroupBy(a=>a).Select(x => x.First());`

Here, `first` will select first record and `groupBy` will group the same values