# How to concatenate field in list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of  objects with field String[]. Objects in list >8000
And i need to get String[] with all values from this field from this
list

i can do this with loop as below.  But can i do this via LINQ (shorter and more efficient) ?

```
List<ProductInfo> productInfos = new List<ProductInfo>();
ProductInfo f1 = new ProductInfo();
f1.tags = new[] { "A","B","T","U"};
ProductInfo f2 = new ProductInfo();
f2.tags = new[] { "C","D","M","U" };
productInfos.Add(f1);
productInfos.Add(f2);

List<String> res = new List<string>();
productInfos.ForEach(f =>
{
    
    foreach (String tag in f.tags)
    {
        res.Add(tag);   
    }
});
res = res.Distinct().ToList();
class ProductInfo
{
    public String[] tags;
}
```

But can i do this with LINQ ?

Comment: `var res = productInfos.SelectMany(p => p.Tags).ToList();`.

Comment: Another dupe target with `Distinct()`: [How to get Distinct elements from a List of List in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34313041/8967612)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany` for that.

```
List<String> res = productInfos.SelectMany(x => x.tags)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use LINQ all the way (with `SelectMany` in this particular case):

```cs
var res = productInfos
    .SelectMany(p => p.tags)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

See also:

- [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) and some more [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/)
- [LINQ Pocket Reference by Joseph Albahari, Ben Albahari](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linq-pocket-reference/9780596519247/)